# How to get PHP curl to return a result in web page on 22.04 LTS?

Tags: apache2, php, curl, php-fpm

I have a web server with the following software installed:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
cPanel 118.0.4
Apache 2.4 with the mod_suphp module
PHP 8.2
```

One of the cPanel accounts runs a Laravel application which interacts with PalPal using curl.  This was transferred from a CentOS 7 server where everything worked.

When I run the PHP equivalent of "curl -X POST https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d <...>" from a bash shell, it returns the expected result.  However, when run in a web page it returns nothing and no errors are logged.

The suggestions in these queries don't help:

[curl is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029273/curl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

[PHP returning blank pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651914/php-returning-blank-pages)

Any others would be welcome!

Comment: In desperation, I substituted AmpHttpClient for curl but got exactly the same behavior.  It's as if the problem is with the firewall, except that it works from a bash shell, so it can't be that.